# Q. Terminate a process called in a function from another function in Python

Tags: python-2.7, function, subprocess, python-multiprocessing, terminate

I wrote a function `fun0` that calls:

1. a subprocess `p1`,
2. a function `fun1`,
3. and a function `fun2` that calls another process `p2`.

The two processes `p1` and `p2` are external files. The code of the function `fun0` is:

```
def fun0():

    # call the 1. process        
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(["python", "script1.py"])
    try:
        p1.wait()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        try:
            p1.terminate()
        except OSError:
            pass
        p1.wait()

    # call the 1. function
    fun1()

    # loop 3 times
    for i in range(1, 3, 1):   

        # call the 2. function
        fun2()

def fun2():

    # call 2. process
    p2 = subprocess.Popen(["python", "script2.py"])
    try:
        p2.wait()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        try:
            p2.terminate()
        except OSError:
            pass
        p2.wait()
```

The script_2.py uses threading to run two functions at the same time. The code is as follows:

```
import threading

def Ref():
    read ref. value
    return ref. value

def Read():
    while read_interval <= some_time:
        read value
        yield value

def Add():
    while delta > error:
        while delta > limit :
            while True:
                value = next(Read())
                delta = change delta
                check conditions
        while True:
            value = next(Read())
            delta = change delta
            check conditions
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':

    t0 = threading.Thread(target = Ref)
    t0.start()
    t0.join()

    readTime = datetime.now()

    t1 = threading.Thread(target = Read)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target = Add)

    t1.start()
    t2.start()

    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

I would like to stop the execution of the function `fun0()` externally i.e. from another function. When the stop occurs, I would also like the functions `fun1`, `fun2` and processes `p1`, `p2` to stop and possibly retrieve the data from them. I wonder which would be an elegant, clean and Pythonic way to do it. I am considering to:

1. threading,
2. multiprocessing,
3. using another function,
4. using signals?

I have read in this [post 28906558](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906558/how-can-i-stop-the-execution-of-a-python-function-from-outside-of-it) on stopping the function using `multiprocessing` should be the way to do it but I would like to hear more opinions, thank you.

Comment: I realize the `p2 subprocess` will not terminate by terminating the functions `Start`. Perhaps the `multiprocessing` method and creating a `process group` is a solution like it is explained in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/4791612/8536248.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of this problem I used simple countdowns for the function `fun1` and for subprocesses `p1` and `p2`. Then I begun experimenting with the function as process solution. The code of the main program is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7 python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#An example of how to terminate the execution of a function
#which calls a process using an external trigger.

import time
import subprocess
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def fun0():

    # start process1        
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(["python", "eg_script1_countdown1.py"])
    p1_PID = p1.pid
    print "p1_PID:", p1_PID
    try:
        p1.wait()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        try:
            p1.terminate()
        except OSError:
            pass
        p1.wait()

    # call function1
    fun1()

    # loop 3 times
    for i in range(1, 3, 1):
        # call fun2
        print "call function 2, loop n.", i
        fun2()

def fun1():
    for i in range(5,0,-1):
        print "fun1 > take five in", i
        time.sleep(1)

def fun2():
    # start process2
    p2 = subprocess.Popen(["python", "eg_script2_countdown2.py"])
    p2_PID = p2.pid
    print "p2_PID:", p2_PID
    try:
        p2.wait()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        try:
            p2.terminate()
        except OSError:
            pass
        p2.wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pMain = Process(target=fun0)
    pMain_PID = pMain.pid
    print "pMain_PID:", pMain_PID
    pMain.start()
    time.sleep(20)
    pMain.terminate()
```

The code of the first called file is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7 python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#eg_script1_countdown.py

import time

for i in range(10,0,-1):
    print "script1.py > have a beer in", i
    time.sleep(1)
```

and of the second file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7 python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#eg_script2_countdown.py

import time

for i in range(10,0,-1):
    print "script2.py > give love in", i
    time.sleep(1)
```

I am changing the line `time.sleep(20)` in `__name__ == '__main__'` to see how the internal termination `pMain.terminate()` affects the result. I found out that:

1. when triggered while the subprocess `p1` is running, it does not terminate it,
2. when triggered while the the `fun1()` is running, it does terminate the function,
3. when triggered while the subprocess `p2` is running, it does not terminate the process but terminates the `fun2()` in the next loop.

How to terminate the subprocesses `p1` and `p2` while running?

Comment: I have read if you mark the subprocesses as daemons, the subprocesses will be terminated immediately if the parent process (i.e. non-daemonic) is terminated. How does this apply to my case?

Answer (score 0):

I did modify the code of the main program using `pMain.daemon = True` before `pMain.start()` as suggested [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32062664/8536248) but the process `p1` still runs in the backgroud even after exiting.

```
import os
import time
import signal
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import multiprocessing
from datetime import datetime

def fun0():

    p1 = subprocess.Popen(["python", "eg_script1_countdown1.py"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    #p1 = subprocess.Popen(["python", "eg_script1_countdown1.py"])
    global p1_pid
    p1_pid = p1.pid
    print "p1_pid:", p1_pid

    try:
        p1.wait()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
       try:
            p1.terminate()
       except OSError:
            pass
       p1.wait()

    # call fun1
    fun1()

    # loop 3 times
    for i in range(3):
        # call fun2
        print "call fun2, loop n.", i
        with open('/home/parovelb/Desktop/Python2.7/log.txt', 'a') as log:
                log.write(str(datetime.now()) + '  for loop n. ' + str(i) + "\n")
        fun2()

def fun1():
    for i in range(5,0,-1):
        print "fun1 > take five in", i
        with open('/home/parovelb/Desktop/Python2.7/log.txt', 'a') as log:
                log.write(str(datetime.now()) + '  fun1 ' + str(i) + "\n")
        time.sleep(1)

def fun2():

    # start process2
    p2 = subprocess.Popen(["python", "eg_script2_countdown2.py"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    #p2 = subprocess.Popen(["python", "eg_script2_countdown2.py"])
    global p2_pid
    p2_pid = p2.pid

    try:
        p2.wait()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        try:
            p2.terminate()
        except OSError:
            pass
        p2.wait()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # original code
    pMain = multiprocessing.Process(target=fun0)
    pMain.daemon = True
    pMain.start()
    time.sleep(10)    
    pMain.terminate()
    exit()
```

Comment: Checking the solution proposed in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true does not solved the problem either.

Answer (score 0):

Following the proposed solutions in the posts [delegate-sigint-signal...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487700/delegate-sigint-signal-to-child-process-and-then-cleanup-and-terminate-the-paren) and [delegate-signal-handling...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936107/delegate-signal-handling-to-a-child-process-in-python) I modified the code of my main program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7 python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
This is an example of a simple terminaton of a subprocess with a ctrl+c. 
"""

import time
import signal
import subprocess


def signal_handler(signal, frame):
   print "outer signal handler"
   exit(2)


def fun1():
   for i in range(5,0,-1):
        print "fun1 > take five in", i
        time.sleep(1)


def execute():

    # call the process first
    proc = subprocess.Popen("python eg_test.py",shell=True)
    try:
        proc.wait()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        try:
            proc.terminate()
        except OSError:
            pass

    # call the function second
    fun1()


def main():

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

    execute()
    time.sleep(5)
    proc.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)


main()
```

I also modified just one of the external scripts just for a test run:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7 python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
This is an example of a simple for loop countdown run a subprocess and
terminated with ctrl+c. 
"""

import time
import signal
from datetime import datetime


def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print "exiting: inner function"
    exit(2)



def main():
    #define the signal handler
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

    # simple for loop countdown
    for i in range(20,0,-1):
        print "test.py > countdown", i
        time.sleep(1)


main()
```

When pressing `ctrl + c` in mid-process (the external script is running), it terminates it and then continues with executing the `fun1()`. The question remains: how to terminate the `execute()` function from another function?

Answer (score 0):

After some trial & error I got the code working. I sense there is a lot of space for improvement. The code of the main script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7 python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
This is an example of a simple terminaton of a subprocess with a ctrl+c. 
"""

import os
import time
import signal
import subprocess
import multiprocessing
from datetime import datetime


p1_pid = 0
proc_pid = 0


def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print " main signal handler "
    # write to log
    with open('.../Python2.7/log.txt', 'a') as log:
            log.write(str(datetime.now()) + ' exiting: main function ' + "\n")
    exit(2)


def f1():
    for i in range(5,0,-1):
        print "f1 > main function", i
        # write to log
        with open('/home/parovelb/Desktop/Python2.7/log.txt', 'a') as log:
            log.write(str(datetime.now()) + ' main function ' + str(i) + "\n")
        time.sleep(1)


def execute():
    # call the function second
    f1()

    # call the process first
    global p1, p1_pid
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(["python", "eg_test.py"], shell=False)
    p1_pid = p1.pid
    print "p1_pid", p1_pid
    try:
        p1.wait()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        try:
            p1.terminate()
        except OSError:
           pass


def kill_them_all():
    time.sleep(10)
    print "p1_pid", p1_pid
    os.kill(p1_pid,signal.SIGINT)
    os.kill(proc_pid,signal.SIGINT)


def main():
    # define signal handler
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)
    global proc, proc_pid    

    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=execute)
    proc_pid = proc.pid
    print "proc_pid", proc_pid
    proc_end = multiprocessing.Process(target=kill_them_all)

    proc.start()
    proc_end.start()

    proc.join()
    proc_end.join()


main()
```

The code of the external script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7 python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import time
import signal
from datetime import datetime


def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print " external signal handler "
    with open('.../Python2.7/log.txt', 'a') as log:
            log.write(str(datetime.now()) + ' exiting: external function ' + "\n")
    exit(2)


def main():
    #define the signal handler
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

    # simple for loop countdown
    for i in range(20,0,-1):
        print "eg_test.py > external file > main function", i
        with open('.../Python2.7/log.txt', 'a') as log:
            log.write(str(datetime.now()) + ' external function ' + str(i) + "\n")
        time.sleep(1)


main()
```